# Stack smashing detected: running program with dinamically allocated array of structures

Tags: c, memory-management, struct

I'm writing the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "planes.h"

int main(void)
{
    plane* planes=NULL;
    int size=0;

    readPlanes(&planes, &size);

    free(planes);
    planes=NULL;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


void readPlanes(plane** planes, int* size)
{
    char buffer[100]={'\0'};
    int airplaneID, modeli;
    float fuel;
    char modelc;
    int invent=0;
    int rettest=0;
    do{
        printf("Enter the number of planes:\n");
        fgets(buffer, 100, stdin);
        rettest=sscanf(buffer, "%d", size);
        if((*size)<=0)
        {
            printf("Invalid number of planes: enter a non negative number\n");
            rettest=0;
        }

    }while(rettest!=1);

    *planes=(plane*)calloc((*size), sizeof(plane*));

    for(invent=0; invent<(*size); invent++)
    {
        planes[invent]=calloc(1, sizeof(plane));

        do{
            rettest=0;
            printf("Enter the airplaneID:\n");
            fgets(buffer, 100, stdin);
            rettest=sscanf(buffer, "%d", &airplaneID);
            if(airplaneID<0)
            {
                printf("Invalid airplaneID: enter a positive number\n");
                rettest=0;
            }

        }while(rettest!=1);

        planes[invent]->airplaneID=airplaneID;

        do{
            rettest=0;
            printf("Enter the model:\n");
            fgets(buffer, 100, stdin);
            rettest=sscanf(buffer, "%c %d", &modelc, &modeli);
            if(modeli<0 || modelc<'A' || modelc>'Z')
            {
                printf("Invalid model: enter an uppercase letter followed by a non negative number\n");
                rettest=0;
            }

        }while(rettest!=2);

        planes[invent]->planemodel.letter=modelc;
        planes[invent]->planemodel.number=modeli;

        do{
            rettest=0;
            printf("Enter the fuel:\n");
            fgets(buffer, 100, stdin);
            rettest=sscanf(buffer, "%f", &fuel);
            if(fuel<0.0f)
            {
                printf("Invalid fuel: enter a non negative number\n");
                rettest=0;
            }

        }while(rettest!=1);

        planes[invent]->fuel=fuel;

    }
}
```

The header file is:

```
#ifndef PLANES_H_INCLUDED
#define PLANES_H_INCLUDED

typedef struct
{
    char letter;
    int number;
}model;


typedef struct
{
    int airplaneID;
    model planemodel;
    float fuel;
}plane;

void readPlanes(plane**, int*);
int lowestFuel(plane*, int);
void printID(plane*, int, char*);


#endif // PLANES_H_INCLUDED
```

Anyway, when I run the program with planes=1 the program runs with no problems. However if I try to run it with 2 or more planes, the following error occurs (at the end of the program, after the user entered all the parameters for all the planes):

***stack smashing detected***: /home/user/Documents/program/bin/Debug/program terminated
Aborted(core dumped)

I have no idea why this is occurring and where is my problem. Can someone help me?

Comment: Standard C does not have "vectors" in the sense of C++'s STL.  It looks like the term you want is probably "array".

Comment: Well, `free(planes)` won't free everything you have allocated, so theoretically you have a memory leak here. But it is not related to the error you see, probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `planes` declared as a `plane **`, this allocation is incorrect:

```
*planes=(plane*)calloc((*size), sizeof(plane*));
```

You are allocating memory to which a `plane *` will point; inasmuch as you are considering that memory as the storage for an array, the elements of the array (e.g. `(*planes)[0]`) must therefore be of type `plane`.  You are not allocating enough space for a `*size` elements of type `plane`, however; only enough for that many *pointers*.

A good form to use for allocations specifies the wanted size in terms of the pointer to which the allocation is being assigned; for example,

```
mytype *p;
p = calloc(n, sizeof (*p));
```

Observe that the size of the allocation is defined in terms of the size of the thing to which `p` points, which is almost always what you want, without hard-coding `p`'s type.  That not only reduces the scope for errors, it is also flexible with respect to changes to `p`'s type.  (Note also that casting the result of `malloc` / `calloc` / `realloc` in C is not only unnecessary, but is regarded by many as poor form.)

In your case, the pointer for which you are allocating is `*planes`, so the above form would be realized as

```
*planes = calloc(*size, sizeof(**planes));
```

You seem to be confused by the double pointer, however.  The only reason for it is to enable `readPlanes()` to modify its caller's local variable.  It does not imply a requirement for multiple levels of allocation.  In particular, having allocated memory and recorded a pointer to it in `*planes`, it makes no sense whatever to subsequently allocate more memory and assign it to `planes[0]`, *which is the same thing*.  It makes even less sense to attempt to assign anything to `planes[1]`, however, because as this function was called, `planes` points to `main`'s pointer `planes`, and therefore `planes[1]` points one `plane*` past that, to ... what?  It's not defined, and your program therefore exhibits undefined behavior.  That's your stack smashing.

In fact, you don't need the allocations in the loop at all -- you have already (after the first correction) allocated all the space you need.  Because you assigned the pointer to `*planes`, you'll want to access it via that pointer; that means using expressions of the form `(*planes)[n]` to reference the `n`<sup>th</sup> plane.  For example,

```
(*planes)[invent].airplaneID = airplaneID;
```

Comment: Hi John Bollinger! Thank you very much for your response.  I understood what you explained about the allocation of memory. However, I still have some issues about the double pointer and why we use it. Is it because you might want readPlanes to change the address of the array of planes(plane*)? If our array wasn't dinamically allocated would we only need a single pointer (representing, of course, the vector)? Thanks!

Comment: @GrangerObliviate, I already addressed the reason to use a double pointer (though it's *your* program -- don't you already know why you did that?).  The only plausible reason is so that function `readPlanes()` can set the value of a variable belonging to its caller, given that the caller cooperates by passing a pointer to that (pointer) variable.